# Can not load MySQL driver weblogic

Tags: mysql, oracle, jdbc, weblogic, driver

I'm trying to connect MySQL database to weblogic so that I can use it in my project, I'm very new to this, anyway, I have created a data-source, I selected MySQL as a database type > I put my database name, host: localhost, port:3306, database username, and password, driver class name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
when ever I test connection it gives: Cannot load driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
I downloaded J-connector I have put it in:

> C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\server\ext\jdbc\mysql

But it's not working!

Comment: Is it required to use WebLogic 11g in your project?

Comment: Normally, you don't need to add any driver other than one that came with a fresh install. Did you want to use any other version of the driver? Also are you getting the error while just defining the Data Source on the Weblogic Console?

Answer (score 0):

What version of mysql are you using?
If it is version 8 of mysql you must update the driver in the Weblogic. In this link https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/
luck